# How to change property values of object passed into a function?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to change the property values of an object I pass into my function. If object has the property (for example 'stuff' it should change its value from some to'new value' - however my code doesn't work-could someone explain why its not working and how I can change the values?
Thank you!!

```
function changeProperties(obj) {
    //  var obj;
    return function() {
            //var properties=
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (arguments.length == 1) {
                    if (key == arguments[0]) {
                        return obj[key];
                    } else {

                        obj[key] = arguments[1];
                        return obj[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    //return obj;
}

var obj = {
    stuff: 'some'
};
var changing = changeProperties(obj);

changing('stuff', 'new value');
obj.stuff;
```

Comment: Your `arguments.length === 1` fails because arguments.length is 2

Comment: Your `else` is nested incorrectly.

Comment: No, the first if statement is for the case where the function gets only ONE argument, (thats when I don't change the value to the second argument so ===1 is correct.

Comment: Look at it again REAL CLOSELY. The else is applying to when the property does not match, NOT when the the number of arguments is 2. You need to move a closing curly bracket up.

Comment: ohhh okay thanks a lot- you are right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have the else nested incorrectly.

But more basically, there is no need to loop through properties. You can just say

```
function changeProperties(obj) {
    return function() {
        if (arguments.length === 2) obj[arguments[0]] = arguments[1];
        return obj[arguments[0]];
    };
}
```

Or perhaps more readably

```
function changeProperties(obj) {
    return function(key, val) {
        if (val !== undefined) obj[key] = val;
        return obj[key];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var changeProperty = function(obj, prop, val) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        obj[prop] = val;
    }
};

var obj = { hello: 'world' };
changeProperty(obj, 'hello', 'test'); // hello: test
changeProperty(obj, 'nonexisting', 'changed value'); // won't be affected
```

EDIT: for multiple properties:

```
var changeProperties = function(obj, changes) {
    for(prop in changes) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            obj[prop] = changes[prop];
        }
    };
};

var obj = { name: 'John', surname: 'Doe' };
changeProperties(obj, { name: 'Abraham', surname: 'Lincoln' });
```

Comment: Because you did not find the problem in the OP's code.

Comment: @javascript2016 I did not downvote it, but perhaps the downvote is due to the problem being a pretty simply logical error, which simply stepping through the code with a debugger would have revealed easily enough.